# Can anybody explain "hold majorities in 33 House delegations" for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand this phrase:

"That’s anybody’s guess, but the current makeup of Congress would appear to put Republicans in the driver’s seat. Republicans **hold majorities in 33 House delegations**, Democrats have majorities in 14, and three are tied. That could change, of course, based on the Nov. 8 results."

Source: http://www.bloomberg.com/politics/articles/2016-11-03/what-happens-if-nobody-wins-the-presidency-quicktake-q-a

Comment: The "33 delegations" are 33 portions of the U.S. House of Representatives, just like the article and the original poster state. The article discusses the U.S. Constitution's provisions for choosing a U.S. President if the Electoral College does not produce a majority for a single candidate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for an explanation of the US political system, but does not ask a specific language related question.

Comment: @haile In 650 characters: in the US, we don't vote for president. Instead, we vote for electors, who elect the president. A state's electors are chosen by the parties according to the number of their representatives. Illinois has 18 representatives: 8 Republicans & 10 Democrats.  States also have 2 senators & 1 elector per senator. Illinois has 1 of each party. Illinois, then, has 11 Democratic electors and 9 Republican.  Repeat for each of the 50 states and you have the 538 members of the electoral college. 270 electoral votes are necessary to prevent the U.S. from being compared to Hungary.

Answer (score 3):

Each state in the United States sends one or more "Representatives" to the United States House of Representatives.  The collection of such "Representatives" from a single state is that state's "delegation".

According to the [Twelfth Amendment](http://www.usconstitution.net/const.html#Am12) to the U.S. Constitution, if no single candidate for President receives "a majority of the whole number of Electors appointed" to the Electoral College, then the House of Representatives chooses the new President.

> But in choosing the President, the votes shall be taken by states, the representation from each state having one vote; a quorum for this purpose shall consist of a member or members from two-thirds of the states, and a majority of all the states shall be necessary to a choice.

The article is pointing out that **if** each state's delegation to the House of Representatives were to vote for President along party lines, it is likely that a majority of the states would vote for a Republican.  There are enough Republicans in other states (such as California) that the Republicans could achieve the required quorum.